# How to import a provider (plugin) from another module?

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-providers

I found a [very helpful Angular plugin](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-modifiers?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-modifiers.plugin.ts) on StackBlitz (code below)

You can directly bind to the *click* event with modifiers like so `(click.shift)="doSomething()"`

When I put the plugin in my module it works just fine

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS,
      useClass: ClickModifiersPlugin,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
```

I have put shared components, general imports etc in a core module which is then the first import in every other module. So naturally I wanted to move the provider to my core module as well. But when I do that, the `(click.shift)` event won't work any longer. The constructor is not even called.

So my question is: **How do I import a plugin provider from another module?**

---

Here is the code of the plugin

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const APPLE_PATTERN = /(mac|iphone|ipod|ipad)/i;
const EVENT_PATTERN = /^click(\.(shift|alt|ctrl)){1,3}$/;

@Injectable()
export class ClickModifiersPlugin {
  manager: EventManager;

  addEventListener(
    target: HTMLElement,
    eventName: string,
    originalHandler: any,
  ): Function {
    const isApple = APPLE_PATTERN.test(navigator.platform);
    const [name, ...keys] = eventName.split(".");
    const modifiers = keys.map(
      key => isApple && key === 'ctrl' ? 'metaKey' : key + 'Key'
    );

    const subscription = fromEvent(target, 'click').pipe(
      filter(e => modifiers.every(modifier => e[modifier])),
    ).subscribe(originalHandler);

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  supports(eventName: string): boolean {
    return EVENT_PATTERN.test(eventName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `providedIn: 'root'` ?